# Use PHP to update MySQL records individually with outside JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, insert-update

I am attempting to loop through a set of records containing IPs for users. I am using the freegeoip.net API service for geolocation. Inside of the users table, I've stored IPs from users of the application and now I'm interested in updating all records individually by making a call to the API, having it return JSON content that I fetch with file_get_contents and then input into 2 fields based on the key (i.e. city, region_name AKA state).

Example of sample data being returned from API: http://freegeoip.net/json/

I have essentially 3 columns: [ip], [city], [state]

I have the IP data populated.

Below is the beginning of my PHP code which is a modification of my SELECT methods. Now I need to execute UPDATE queries individually. Inside of the file_get_contents is the API URL for freegeoip.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_log");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $row['ip']);
        $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
        echo "<br />The IP is: " . $row['ip'];
        echo "<br />The Location is: " . $parsedJson;
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Question**: How would I modify this code to loop through each MySQL record (based on IP column) and update the relevant fields data (city and state) received from my API?

Comment: question is a bit unclear. What exactly you are trying to achieve? Do you want to store $parsedJson data somewhere?

Comment: I've updated with a what is hopefully a clearer question.

Comment: $parsedJson after decoding is an array - so to get city and state yuo can use the following code

`$parsedJson['city'] $parsedJson['country_name']` can use any other value that is being returned from the API to get the list of values you can do `print_r($parsedJson);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Loop through your IPs
- Fetch the geo location
- Update the record

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT(`ip`) AS ip FROM user_log");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $row['ip']);
        $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent, true);
        echo "<br />The IP is: " . $row['ip'];
        echo "<br />The Location is: " . $parsedJson['city'];

        $strDbQuery = "UPDATE user_log SET city = ?, state = ? WHERE ip = ?";
        $objUpdate = mysqli_prepare($con, $strDbQuery);
        if($objUpdate) {
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($objUpdate, 'sss', $parsedJson['city'], $parsedJson['region_name'], $row['ip']); 
             mysqli_stmt_execute($objUpdate);
        } else {
           echo "Cannot update for ip ". $row['ip'] . PHP_EOL;
        }

}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: My apologies, they use "region_name" instead of "state". Thank you for the answer. Attempting it now.

Comment: Made that change in my answer. Also checked if `prepare` was successful before binding and executing. Also fetched unique ip's from the table.

Comment: Received an error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/localeupdate.php on line 17    which would be "mysqli_stmt_bind_param....."

Comment: My bad. Try now. I've added `,true` to `json_decode`. (I prefer the array approach to json decode`)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

/* check connection */
if ($con->connect_errno) {
   die("Connect failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `user_log`");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $row['ip']);
    $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE `user_log` SET `city` = ?, `region_name` = ? WHERE `ip` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $parsedJson['city'], $parsedJson['region_name'], $row['ip']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```